# Trying to understand the answer to a code snippet in the book Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is the snippet of code from Chapter 3 of Eloquent JavaScript.

```js
const power = function(base, exponent) {
  let result = 1;
  for (let count = 0; count < exponent; count++) {
    result *= base;
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(power(2, 10));
// 1024
```

This is how I explained it to myself. However I am at a loss for truly understanding why 1024 is returned can somoene break it down for me?

```
/* 
    Explanation of code above.

     - We created a function named power. We used a function expression notation to create it. 
     
     - power has two parameters base and exponent.

     - the body of the function contains the code that the function will execute. 

    - the body does the following:

        1. declares a variable called result which has a value of 1.
        
        2. There is a for loop. Here are the parts of the for loop:

            - The intializer: the variable count is declared and assigned a value of 0

            - We are looking at the condition to see if it is truthy. The condition is whether count is greater than exponent. The loop will continue to iterate until this condition is truthy.

            - The incrementer: count will go up by 1 each iteration of the loop

            - The body of the for loop (the code to be executed) states that the result variable is equal to result *= base OR result = result * base 
    
    - then the function will return the value of result 

    - we are done with the function 

    - outside of the function we invoke it using console.log() and pass it the arguments 2 and 10 (base, exponent). 

    - The computer plugs the arguments into the function. The computer evaluates the condition in the for loop to see if its truthy. Basically, the computer asks is count < exponent? Count = 0 and exponent = 10. So the condition evaluates to falsey. 


    const power = function (2, 10) {
    let result = 1;
    for (let count = 0; 11 < 10; count++) {
                    1   10
                    2   10
                    3   10
                    4   10
                    5   10
                    6   10
                    7   10
                    8   10
                    9   10
                    10  10
                    11  10
                    
        result *= base; => 2 = 2 * 10
    }
    return result;

};

console.log(power(2,10));


*/
```

I was expecting result *= base, or result = result * base. I know I am missing something with the iterations.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for(let count = 0; count < exponent; count++) {
  result *= base;
}
```

You've understood the result of this wrong it seems. Notice that the `count` variable is just used to control the number of iterations of the loop. Each iteration you update the `result` variable to contain a new value by multiplying it with the `base` value, which is then used in the next calculation. So it will be like this.

```
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
4 * 2 = 8
8 * 2 = 16
16 * 2 = 32
32 * 2 = 64
64 * 2 = 128
128 * 2 = 256
256 * 2 = 512
512 * 2 = 1024
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation helped. I made a note to myself that count is just used to control the number of loop iterations and that helped me understand better.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you are satisfied with the answer you can click the checkmark to the left to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`result *= base` is shorthand for `result = result * base`. Thus, instead of your Loop analysis, the following is correct:

```
const power = function (2, 10) {
    let result = 1;
    for (let count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
       count = 0: result = 1 * 2 = 2
       count = 1: result = 2 * 2 = 4
       count = 2: result = 4 * 2 = 8
       count = 3: result = 8 * 2 = 16
       count = 4: result = 16 * 2 = 32
       count = 5: result = 32 * 2 = 64
       count = 6: result = 64 * 2 = 128
       count = 7: result = 128 * 2 = 256
       count = 8: result = 256 * 2 = 512
       count = 9: result = 512 * 2 = 1024
       count = 10: Stop, as  10 < 10 is not valid
    }
    return result (= 1024);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time to answer, and it helped me understand better.